# Is it possible to put a system output into a var in javascript?

Tags: javascript, child-process

Is there a way to put the result of a system shell output into a var for example:

```
exec('echo test', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
    return;
  }
  console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
});
```

and save the console log output into a var

Comment: stdout is your  result you want to put in a varaible right ?

Comment: `stdout` *is* a variable that you can use?

Comment: @RenaldoBalaj yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways! First, you should note that in your example above stdout is already available in the appropriately-named variable:

```js
exec('echo test', (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
    console.error(`exec error: ${error}`);
    return;
  }
  console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`); // right here
});
```

However, I would assume you want to be able to access that value outside of your callback. You could rely on the fact that `exec` returns a [`ChildProcess`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_class_childprocess) which in turn exposes a readable stream representing the stdout of the process:

```js
const subprocess = exec('echo test')
let stdout = "";
subprocess.stdout.on('data', (chunk) => {
  stdout += chunk.toString();
});
subprocess.stdout.on('end', () => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`); // stdout is now complete
});
```

But you should also note there that although the variable is technically accessible outside of the callback, it's not actually *ready* until after another callback. This is because `exec` is asynchronous, so its result will likewise need to be accessed asynchronously.

If this presents a problem for your use case, one alternative is to execute your child process synchronously using [`execSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options), in which case your stdout is simply returned directly from the call as a buffer:

```
const stdout = execSync('echo test').toString();
```

Comment: `result = stdout;` makes no sense. `stdout` already is a variable (as good as any), and `result` won't be usable outside the callback anyway.

Comment: I agree it's a silly pattern; I inferred from the question that the OP wanted stdout in a variable outside the callback, and tried to accommodate.

Comment: No, I mean it is a pattern that just won't work, and the OP will be pretty confused when he tries it.

Comment: that's a good point; I think I corrected too far in favor of trying to work with the OP's expectations and ended up too far away from an answer that could stand by itself. I updated the answer to hopefully be a little more clear!